# AngularJS ignora content-type para requisições GET

Tags: angularjs, http-request

Em minha aplicação Angular 1, estou utilizando `$httpProvider` para poder setar por default em todos os métodos o content-type, porém para os métodos GET, ele não envia em seu cabeçalho. Como posso forçar o angular para setar o content-type nos métodos GET?

#### No config

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

#### Console

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Request

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é o comportamento correto e esperado.

Métodos `HTTP` `GET` e `DELETE` não possuem *payload*; tanto clientes quanto servidores não são obrigados a implementar interpretadores para um cabeçalho `content-Type` nestas operações.

Os métodos que portam *payload*, como `POST` ou `PUT`, podem conter o cabeçalho em suas requisições.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Comment: É isso mesmo. Olhando o JS do angular, a própria classe responsável por enviar os requests ao servidor deleta o content-type quando não existe um payload na solicitação.